# Casting IEnumerable<T> to List<T>

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

I was wondering if it is possible to cast an `IEnumerable` to a `List`. Is there any way to do it other than copying out each item into a list?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

As already suggested, use `yourEnumerable.ToList()`. It enumerates through your `IEnumerable`, storing the contents in a new `List`. You aren't necessarily copying an existing list, as your `IEnumerable` may be generating the elements lazily.

This is exactly what the other answers are suggesting, but clearer. Here's the disassembly so you can be sure:

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    return new List<TSource>(source);
}
```

Comment: will it throw an error if IEnumerable is not null but empty ?

Comment: @SumitJoshi no it won't throw an error. An IEnumerable can be empty.

Answer (score 52):

```
using System.Linq;
```

Use the .ToList() method.  Found in the System.Linq namespace.

```
var yourList = yourEnumerable.ToList();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=netcore-2.2

Comment: If not available using System.Linq is missing :). This should totally be the accepted answer...

Comment: Also if it's not available, you may have forgotten to declare your IEnumerable with its <T>.

Comment: Very simple and to the point, thanks! Maybe use a null-conditional operator in `yourEnumerable?.ToList();` to take into account the possibility that `yourEnumerable` might be `null`?

Answer (score 7):

As others suggested, simply use the `ToList()` method on an enumerable object:

```
var myList = myEnumerable.ToList()
```

But, if your object implementing the **[`IEnumerable` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1) doesn't have the `ToList()` method** and you're getting an error like the following:

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'

...you're probably missing the [`System.Linq` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq), because the [`ToList()` method is an extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist) provided by that namespace, it's not a member of the `IEnumerable` interface itself.

So **just add the namespace** to your source file:

```
using System.Linq
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a new List and pass the old IEnumerable to its initializer:

```
    IEnumerable<int> enumerable = GetIEnumerable<T>();
    List<int> list = new List<int>(enumerable);
```

Comment: there will anyway need to be a copy.

Answer (score 2):

#### Another gotcha (async call)

An async call may be your problem.  If you added the using System.Linq statement and you are still getting the error "does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no accessible extension method...", look carefully for the Task keyword in your error message.

#### Original Call (works)

```cs
IEnumerable<MyDocument> docList = await _documentRepository.GetListAsync();
```

#### Attempt to use ToList (still not working)

So...if you are doing this and it does NOT work

```cs
List<MyDocument> docList = await _documentRepository.GetListAsync().ToList();
```

#### Use parenthesis

You are actually calling ToList on the Task<IEnumerable>! **Add parenthesis** around your await call like this

```cs
List<MyDocument> docList = (await _documentRepository.GetListAsync()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

no, you should copy, if you are sure that the reference is reference to list, you can convert like this

```
List<int> intsList = enumIntList as List<int>;
```

Comment: If you're *sure* that it's a reference to a list, you should use a direct cast so that it will throw an exception if you're wrong. Use "as" if you think it *might* be a List<T> but you're not sure, and neither are error conditions. Then test whether the result is null.

Comment: Maybe add an 'if (intsList == null) intsList = new List<int>(enumIntList);' if it *might* be a 'List<int>', already, but there are some cases where it is not.