# LINQ query on DataTable AsEnumerable returns null

Tags: c#, linq

In the below code block, my `DataTable` TelemetryFile is correctly populated. The first MessageBox displays 4.

It also correctly contains a column called FixName. The second MessageBox displays FixName.

However, something is going wrong when I try to create a List<(string FixOrReportName, long CountInTelemetryFile)> of the different FixName values in the table and how often they occur. sortedCountsByName is null and the third MessageBox diplays Hmm.

What am I doing wrong?

---

```
    public List<(string FixOrReportName, long CountInTelemetryFile)> GetMostPopularOptionsFromTelemetryFile(string typeToReturn, int maxOptionsToReturn)
    {
        this.TelemetryFile.DefaultView.RowFilter = "FixOrReport = '" + typeToReturn + "'";
        MessageBox.Show(this.TelemetryFile.DefaultView.Count.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(this.TelemetryFile.Columns[3].ColumnName);

        var sortedCountsByName = (
            this.TelemetryFile.AsEnumerable()
           .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("FixName"))
           .Select(x => new Tuple<string, long>(x.Key, x.Count()))
        ) as List<(string FixOrReportName, long CountInTelemetryFile)>;

        if (sortedCountsByName is null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hmm");
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            sortedCountsByName.Sort(
                delegate (
                    (string FixOrReportName, long CountInTelemetryFile) firstPair,
                    (string FixOrReportName, long CountInTelemetryFile) nextPair)
                {
                    return -1 * firstPair.CountInTelemetryFile.CompareTo(nextPair.CountInTelemetryFile);
                }
            );
        }

        return sortedCountsByName.Take(maxOptionsToReturn).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: You're mixing old `Tuple`s with new C#7 value tuples. Remove the `as` conversion and proceed from there.

Comment: @GertArnold Out of curiosity, is there a way for me to use new C#7 tuples inside the LINQ query? I tried several things but wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: @puzzlepiece87 Just do `Select(x => (x.Key, x.Count())`

Comment: @juharr I followed your suggestion, though with `Convert.ToInt64(x.Count())` to make the types match. Unfortunately, null was still returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  .Select(x => new Tuple<string, long>(x.Key, x.Count()))
> ```

That's old `Tuple` syntax.

With C# 7 value tuples it should be:

```
.Select(x => (FixOrReportName: x.Key, CountInTelemetryFile: (long)x.Count())
```

Add `ToList()`, and you can remove the `as` conversion.

Comment: This could very well be correct, but when I tried it before and now, it says: `new cannot be used with tuple type. Use a tuple literal expression instead.

I'm using VS 2019 with a project targeting .Net Framework 4.7.2, so I believe I'm on C#7.3, if that helps.

Comment: Your edit solved the compile error, thank you. I'll run it again and accept if it works.

Answer (score -3):

The issue is with this `as`

```
.Select(x => new Tuple<string, long>(x.Key, x.Count()))
        ) as List<(string FixOrReportName, long CountInTelemetryFile)>;
```

`Select()` will return an `IEnumerable<Tuple<string,int>>` rather than a `List<T>`.

Comment: Are you saying you can't convert IEnumerable<T> to List<T>? Because you [can, though maybe I'm doing it incorrectly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961375/casting-ienumerablet-to-listt)