# Casting Task<IEnumerable<T>> to List from a async method in non non-async context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, casting

I am having a Repository method GetSubContracts() that is typically invoked as await and it works fine. I am trying to use the same in a non task/async operation such as a Button click Handler event. I would like to do on of the two options.

1. Call the async method without async as explained in the below article
   https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Blogs/Tool-Tracker/2019/10/calling-methods-async.aspx
2. Cast the Task<IEnumerable> to List

This is because I don’t get .ToList() option when using GetSubContacts in an non Task/await context.

The result. Is also not giving me a Cast or TypeOf options.

I tried various options including what seems to be similar topic here

[Casting IEnumerable<T> to List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961375/casting-ienumerablet-to-listt)

On a general note, should I be adding to the above post or ask a new question here as I am doing now?

Code below.

```
 public List<SubContract> SubContracts; 
public List<SubContract> SubContractsOfSelectedSites = new List<SubContract>();


protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Sites = (await SitesService.GetSites()).ToList();
    SubContracts = (await SubContractsService.GetSubContracts()).ToList();
}



private void  GenerateContractListHandler(MouseEventArgs args)
{
    SubContractsTabDisabled = false;
    //Get the result as Task<IEnumerable<SubContract>>
    var result = (SubContractsService.GetSubContracts());
    SubContractsOfSelectedSites =result.
```

Comment: Does something prevent you making GenerateContractListHandler async?

Comment: @Abraham An `Event Handler` is an exception to the rule to not use `async void`. You can safely make the method `async` and `await` your call to the database. [should-i-avoid-async-void-event-handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415646/should-i-avoid-async-void-event-handlers)

Comment: `.Result` is a really bad idea, as it will often cause a deadlock

Comment: Thanks all. The proposed solution worked.

Comment: For my understanding, is it possible to cast IEnumerable to List as the second option that I was trying?

Answer (score -1):

You can call a async method in a non async function by simply assigning it to a variable then adding .wait();

```
var test = GetSubContracts()
test.Wait();
```

Hope this helps :)

You also might use after with its various options.

```
test.Result
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is it really required to wait specially if it is a long running query? for now, the below worked for me.  private async void  GenerateContractListHandler(MouseEventArgs args)
    {

        SubContractsTabDisabled = false;
      
        SubContractsOfSelectedSites =  (await SubContractsService.GetSubContracts()).ToList();

Comment: I personally have had issues trying to call a async function in a non async function without using an wait() but I could be wrong.

Comment: It was downvoted because the advice to use `.Wait()` and `.Result` in lieu of `await` is a bad idea 99.9% of the time, and furthermore, unnecessary to solve the OP's problem.