# How To Retrieve Group Of Elements From IEnumerable Without Iterating

Tags: list, collections, ienumerable

I have the following:

`IEnumerable<Personel> personel= page.Retrieve<Personel>....`

Then I have List which contains only personelIDs

```
List<int> personelIDs....
```

I need to retrived all 'personels' from the IEnumerable and assign it into a new List which matches the personelIDs from 'personelIDs ' list.

I can do it my iterating and having verify the IDs and if they're equal assign it into another List,
but is there a short here where I can retrieve it without iterating or having multiple lines of code?

```
Basically Is there a way on how to shortened this 

List<int> pIds = ....// contains only specific personellID's
IEnumerable personelIEn = // contains Personel data like personel IDs, name..etc

        List<Personel> personel = personelIEn.ToList();
        List<Personel> personelByTag = new List<Personel>();
        foreach (Personel b in personel ) {
            if (pIds.Contains(b.DocumentID)) {
                personelByTag .Add(b);
            }
        }
       
        return personelByTag ;
```

basically I'm trying to  find ways how to shortened the above code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Casting IEnumerable<T> to List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961375/casting-ienumerablet-to-listt)

Comment: I have modified my question above with some code snippet for more clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a predicate:

```
public List<Personel> search(String documentId, List<Personel> list)
{
   Predicate<Personel> predicate = (Personel personel) => (personel.Id== documentId);

   return list.FindAll(predicate);
}
```

Could that help?

Comment: Yes,  but I have modified a bit because the documentId is a list. ` Predicate<Personel> predicate = (Personel personel) => (documentIds.Contains(personel.DocumentID ));` - Thank you